Flutter Web build failing with JSObject superclass issue in web package
I'm working on a Flutter web project, and I've encountered a compilation issue when trying to build the web version of my app. The error messages are related to the web package and JSObject superclass issues. Here are the details of the errors:
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/web-0.3.0/lib/src/dom/webxr_hit_test.dart:55:34:
Error: The type 'JSObject' can't be used as supertype.
class XRHitTestSource implements JSObject {}
                                 ^
...
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/web-0.3.0/lib/src/helpers/events/providers.dart:615:9:
Error: The method 'typeofEquals' isn't defined for the class 'EventTarget'.
  if (e.typeofEquals('undefined')) {
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
...


Here is my pubspec.yaml:
name: v3_mvp
description: "A new Flutter project."
publish_to: 'none'
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.2.3 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  http: ^1.1.1
  go_router: ^14.1.3
  url_launcher: ^6.2.6
  kpostal: ^0.5.1
  equatable: ^2.0.5
  syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^25.1.40
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.1
  permission_handler: ^11.3.1
  image_picker_web: ^3.1.1
  image_picker: ^1.0.7
  flutter_form_builder: ^9.2.1
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.7
  provider: ^6.1.2
  dio: ^5.4.2+1
  firebase_storage: ^11.6.9
  firebase_core: ^2.26.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.17.8
  cloud_firestore: ^4.15.8
  fl_chart: ^0.67.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
dartz: ^0.10.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

I have tried the following steps to resolve the issue, but none of them worked:

Running flutter clean
Running flutter pub get
Updating all dependencies to their latest versions

